# Share Sheet in iOS not showing Image of the website

Tags: ios, ionic4, socialshare

I have implemented an Ionic project in which you can share a link to the social media using the Native Share action sheet link popup in ios. All works well except that when the sharing window is open(the native ios window) i dont see the image of my website. What could be wrong?

I am using Ionic 4 and https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing plugin.

I am creating the Branch link using below code

```
data: {
        'custom_bool': true,
        'custom_int': Date.now(),
        '$og_title': 'project name',
        '$og_description': 'some text' ,
        '$og_image_url': this.projectData.projectImage,
        "$custom_fields": {"projectId": this.projectData.projectId},
      }
    };

    branch.link(linkData, (err, link)=> {
      console.log(link);
      this.projectData.shareURL = link;
      // use this URL in another page, some logic
    })
```

using the Plugin (SocialSharing) I am doing the below code

```
socialSharing.share("some text", "some text", null, 'this is the previous obtained URL')
```

[This is what I mean by icon not seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAptn.jpg)

Comment: The code snippet will be really great to understand.

Comment: Updated the question :) thanks. I keep forgetting this